# How to store french characters in c++

Tags: c++, character-encoding

I've been trying it for an hour searched everything.

I tried using this `wchar_t c=L'é';` it didn't work.

It gave me an `Invalid argument` at that line in **dev-cpp**
When I ran this directly with **g++ in cmd**  I got 
 `error: converting to execution character set: Invalid argument`
How can we solve this?

**EDIT**

Code:

```
#include<string.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
  wchar_t ccc=L'é';
  wchar_t ar[]=L"é";
  wchar_t bf[]=L"a";
  wchar_t cd;
}
```

**EDIT** Dev-C++ compiler, Windows-7

Comment: In what way does it not work? It should, IIRC.

Comment: @mwerschy Invalid argument error

Comment: @pinkpanther Then its pretty likely you have an error elsewhere but not with this particular character value!

Comment: You should try including `<wstring>` instead of `<string.h>`

Comment: I just compiled it perfectly fine, the debugger says the chars work. Tried writing to file, works too.

Comment: @g-makulik that gave me no such file or directory error i'm using dev-cpp

Comment: Isn't `setlocale` avaliable in `<locale.h>` or `<clocale>`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 I included those libraries upon your suggestion but still getting the error

Comment: You may need make sure that the code page you set for the source code when compiling supports those characters.

Comment: @BlueWanderer what is code page?

Comment: Seems it's called "input charset" in gcc.

Comment: @BlueWanderer I don't really think that this is the problem here, if the character (symbol) is not known the compiler would choke with a different error message IMHO.

Comment: Do consider that this might be your *editor* that screws up and turned the accented character into a byte that the compiler isn't happy with.  Dev-C++'s reputation is not a great one.  If it has an option to save files in utf-8 encoding then try that.  If not then avoid the issue entirely by putting character codes in your source with the `\x` escape.

Comment: @HansPassant you are excellent....you thought differently than others ...please post this as an answer...you have solved my problem....

Comment: I'll skip, too many Dev-C++ fans around.  Please post your own answer and accept it.

Comment: @HansPassant but you still say it isn't that reputed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem solved by the comment by [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant)

There may be many reasons for this problem as pointed in comments. But the problem for me is solved by changing the editor. I was using `Dev-cpp`  and probably that caused the problem. I used `Geany` and got it compiled successfully. But `Dev-cpp` was bitter with me in this instance.

**For future visitors:** Editor could be a problem if you encounter the problem stated in the question.